# liferay-ui: discussion tag in custom portlet

Tags: liferay

I am trying to to imped  inside jsp page custom portlet 
to allow comments on journal article displayed

to embed  .
The problem is it throws g.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.view_jsp as following

```
An error occurred at line: 119 in the jsp file: /discussion.jsp
The method setClassName(String) in the type DiscussionTag is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ? extends JournalArticle>)
116:            id="journalCommentsPanel" persistState="<%= true %>"
117:            title='<%= LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "Comments") %>'>
118:
119:            <liferay-ui:discussion
120:            className="<%= journal.getClass() %>"
121:            classPK="31575"
122:            formAction="www.google.com"
```

15:57:13,540 ERROR [PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:108]

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.jsp.discussion_jsp
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   
org.apache.jsp.discussion_jsp
```

This is my discussion.jsp page

```
<%
WindowState windowState = null;
PortletMode portletMode = null;

PortletURL currentURLObj = null;

if (renderRequest != null) {
    windowState = renderRequest.getWindowState();
    portletMode = renderRequest.getPortletMode();
    currentURLObj = PortletURLUtil.getCurrent(renderRequest,
            renderResponse);
} else if (resourceRequest != null) {
    windowState = resourceRequest.getWindowState();
    portletMode = resourceRequest.getPortletMode();
    currentURLObj = PortletURLUtil.getCurrent(resourceRequest,
            resourceResponse);
}

String currentURL = currentURLObj.toString();

ThemeDisplay themeDisplayObject = (ThemeDisplay) request
        .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
//long groupId = ParamUtil.getLong(request, "groupId", scopeGroupId);
long groupId = themeDisplayObject.getScopeGroupId();

String url = PortalUtil.getCurrentURL(request);
String[] urlString = url.split("/");
String urlTitle = urlString[urlString.length - 1];
urlTitle = HttpUtil.decodeURL(urlTitle).trim();

JournalArticle journal = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil
        .getArticleByUrlTitle(groupId, urlTitle);
 %>

<portlet:actionURL var="discussionUrl">
    <!-- <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/discussion.jsp" /> -->
</portlet:actionURL>


<portlet:actionURL var="editGreetingURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/view.jsp" />
</portlet:actionURL>


<liferay-ui:panel-container extended="<%= false %>"
    id="journalCommentsPanelContainer" persistState="<%= true %>">
    <liferay-ui:panel collapsible="<%= true %>" extended="<%= true %>"
        id="journalCommentsPanel" persistState="<%= true %>"
        title='<%= LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "Comments") %>'>
        <portlet:actionURL name="invokeTaglibDiscussion" var="discussionURL" />
        <liferay-ui:discussion 
        className="<%= JournalArticle.class.getName() %>"
        classPK="<%= journal.getArticleId() %>" 
        formAction="www.google.com"
        subject="Wall Comments"
        userId="<%= journal.getUserId() %>" />
    </liferay-ui:panel>
</liferay-ui:panel-container>


and this is my processAction method :


        PortletConfig portletConfig = getPortletConfig();
    //  System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> inside invoke");
         PortalClassInvoker .invoke(true, "com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.action.EditDiscussionAction",       
                          "processAction", new String[] {
                                          "org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping",
                                          "org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm",
                                          PortletConfig.class.getName(),
                                          ActionRequest.class.getName(),
                                         ActionResponse.class.getName()
                          }, null, null, portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error shows this code at line-120 `className="<%= journal.getClass() %>"` but your `discussion.jsp` shows `className="<%= JournalArticle.class.getName() %>"` which is the corrected version I suppose.

I think the portlet is not deployed properly, try re-deploying the portlet or if that does not help try the usual:

1. undeploy the portlet
2. and then redeploy

if that does not work:

1. undeploy
2. stop server
3. clear temp directory
4. clear work directory
5. start server
6. deploy the portlet

Answer (score 1):

my one is working properly

**my table, WallEntry.** Where userid is the id of the user.

```
List<WallEntry> wallEntry= WallEntryLocalServiceUtil.findByUserId(userId);
for (int i=0;i<wallEntry.size();i++)
{
 WallEntry wallobj=wallEntry.get(i);
 long id=wallobj.getWallEntryId();
}
```

**portlet action url**

```
<portlet:actionURL name="discussionURL" var="discussionURL">
        <portlet:param name="myaction" value="addComments" />
 </portlet:actionURL>
```

**liferay-ui:discussion tag**

```
<liferay-ui:discussion 
    redirect="<%= themeDisplay.getURLCurrent() %>"  
    classPK="<%= wallEntry.getWallEntryId() %>" 
    userId="<%= user.getUserId() %>" 
    className="<%= WallEntry.class.getName() %>"   
    subject="" 
    formAction="<%= discussionURL %>" 
    formName='<%= "fm"+wallEntry.getWallEntryId() %>'  
  />
```

**action class**

```
public void discussionURL(ActionRequest request,ActionResponse response) 
  throws Exception 
     {
     System.out.println("Inside addDiscussion function: "+request.getParameter("myaction"));

     }
```

may be it is helpful for someone.